# Error: done() invoked with non-Error: {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, testing, phantomjs

I'm trying to set up automatic testing, using Mocha and PhantomJS on Selenium with Node. I'm using `selenium-webdriver` library since it seems to be a popular one, but **when I run the test and try to extract data from a page, it gives me this error:**

```
  1) Test "before each" hook for "Test":
     Error: done() invoked with non-Error: {}
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
```

I'm not sure why this problem is happening, and searching didn't help because the solutions I had didn't fit my scenario; I'm on:

- Mac OS X 10
- Node.js v4.4.5
- PhantomJS 2.1.1

Here's my script:

```
var selenium = require("selenium-webdriver");
var should = require("should");

var URL = "https://android.com";
var driver;

describe("Test", function() {
    this.timeout(15000);

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        driver = new selenium.Builder()
            .withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.phantomjs())
            .build();
        driver.get(URL).then(done);
    });

    /* is this an HTML page? */
    it("Test", function() {
        driver
            .getPageSource()
            .should.eventually
            .match(/(.*)\<\!doctype\ html\>(.*)/i);
    });

    afterEach(function(done) {
        driver.quit().then(done);
    });
});
```

I've also tried using some gulp scripts I found and other Node.js libraries but they all return different errors ;~;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything passed to the `done` callback as a parameter will be interpreted as an error. Change `beforeEach` to:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    driver = new selenium.Builder()
        .withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.phantomjs())
        .build();
    driver.get(URL).then(function(){
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for your help! Apparently it was being passed an empty object :/

Comment: Sure, glad to help :)

Comment: I'm afraid your first statement is a little on the false side : `Error: done() invoked with non-Error: 500`

Comment: So many things are on the false side on 2021  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Have since moved away from selenium, feel free to correct/update the answer